# Yelp API (fusion) in React front-end project

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

I want to build some front-end React project (just in learning purpose) ...like some Google MAP and some businesses over it from Yelp API.
I use create-react-app to make it.

I made research in web and it's looks like Yelp API doesn't respond to browsers.

I need general idea how I can implement Yelp API in my project. Maybe I need additional Node module or something else... Just General way hot to do that.

Thanks!

Comment: You can use yelp api from the browser.
https://www.yelp.com/developers/documentation/v3/business_search

Use this to make a GET request. 

On the React side, I like to use Axios to organize my requests. 
Just as a first step, you should create a button and call the above yelp api on click. 

Resource for your reference : https://hackernoon.com/tutorial-how-to-make-http-requests-in-react-part-3-daa6b31b66be

Comment: Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: It didn't help. Its impossible get access to Yelp API from javascript code: 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' issue.

Comment: Oh yeah, just checked their Github, you'll atleast need a Node or python script